# Trying to utilise a field in multiple methods and a runtime error occurs after it seems like my field isn't being used

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get my field / list working. I want to add to the list and use the list in `CheckUserInput` and `PlayerMove` methods. It says it's not being used but I am using it in those methods without any errors.

I tried to play around with it for a bit and all the methods are static methods so I had to make a static field.

```
private static List<string> AlreadyUsed = new List<string>();

private static void CheckUserInput(ref int player, ref string answer, ref bool error)
    {
        AlreadyUsed.Add("");

        if(int.Parse(answer) > 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered a value outside the array. Skipping your turn.");
            error = true;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                if (AlreadyUsed[i] == "X" || AlreadyUsed[i] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have already entered a value in this slot. Skipping your turn.");
                    error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


private static void PlayerMove(ref string answer, string[] arr, ref int player) //make whole new class for this method?
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) //make player move
        {
            if (answer == arr[i])
            {
                if (player == 1)
                {
                    arr[i] = "X";
                    AlreadyUsed.Add(answer);
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i] = "O";
                    AlreadyUsed.Add(answer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I used `CheckUserInput` before `PlayerMove` hence adding the extra value in the list. I was met with a runtime error.

Thank you!

Comment: That isn't what the error message says. Please share the **exact** error message.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)` Talk me through what you think will happen when you access the 3rd item in a list containing only 1 entry. Also have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netframework-4.8 .

Comment: Sorry for not putting in the error message, however I got a NullReferenceException and found the source of the problem by looking at the error message. I'm not sure how I can copy the error message but it said: Object reference not set to an instance of an object but since it's static I would've thought I didn't have to instantiate it or am I missing something here? Also can the other person see the comment I had made even-though it is marked as a duplicate as I still have a question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in *CheckUserInput* method you iterating the list *AlreadyUsed* till index 9 but your code shows that the list *AlreadyUsed* would not have that many items to iterate and an Index out of range exception would occur.

In that *for loop* all you trying to check if *AlreadyUsed* contains strings "X" or "O", no need for the *for loop* you could do that with Contains method, replace your *for loop* in *CheckUserInput* method with this code:

```
if (AlreadyUsed.Contains("X") || AlreadyUsed.Contains("O"))
{
  Console.WriteLine("You have already entered a value in this slot. Skipping your turn.");
  error = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however it seems like on top of this code, I needed to set the object's reference to an instance of the object but I thought this wouldn't be required since it is static?

Comment: static class cannot be instantiated but this thing doesn't apply for a static field!